# Memory comsumption of a process initiated by Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

Is there a way to limit memory consumption of a process initiated by java processbuilder ? 
or 
to get the maximum memory used by the process?

I have tried using the following code..but is always returns 0.

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(command);
before=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
Process pp = p.start();
after=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
System.out.println("Used : "+before-after);
```

I am a beginner..please pardon if the question is silly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the processes started using `ProcessBuilder` are operating system processes and there is no way to control the way to limit their resources from JVM/using Java APIs. You could however try to limit resources, after getting PID of the `Process` using operating system APIs (for example, [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) on Linux).

Also, this:

```
after = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

is not related to `ProcessBuilder` (apart from some allocation Java is making for `ProcessBuilder` object) the way you think. It returns memory of Java Runtime, not the process you have started using `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

`ProcessBuilder` constructors provide a way to set arguments to the program.
For example you have :

```
public ProcessBuilder(String... command)
```

where the command argument vargs contain the program but also its arguments if provided.

And you have also a constructor that provides the same goal but with a `List` as parameter :

```
public ProcessBuilder(List<String> command)
```

In your case, if your program is a Java program, you could write something like that to limit to 512M the maximum memory used by the process :

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = 
        new ProcessBuilder(pathToTheJavaCommand, "-Xmx512m", "-cp", classpath, yourClass);
```

In the case of your program is not a Java program, either your program provides a parameter to set the max memory allocated for it or you shoud use a OS specific feature that limits the consumed memory. But the second case is not necessary fine as it may have critical side effects on the started program if the memory is absolutely required for the program.

At last, `Runtime.getRuntime()` returns the runtime object associated with the current Java application, not the runtime object of the last launched `Process`.

Comment: What would be a good solution to limit CPU/resource usage by a linux command such as cURL using ProcessBuilder? Is there a possibility to achieve this?